# Checking label text and verifying that input field tied to it has at least x amount characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm super new to this language. I have the ability to check for the label sting but I want to make sure that the input field next to it has at least 6 digits (numerical if possible)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label:contains('6 digit')") //i get lost here
});
```

Markup:

```
<form>
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check"> 
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example, including a sample HTML structure and what exactly do you want to test? Do you want to verify that the user only provided 6 digits in the input field? Btw, jQuery is just a library, JavaScript is the language.

Comment: Some fields have 6 digit labels that need to be checked for the 6 digits in the field. Is this even possible.

Comment: Why not use a validation plugin -> http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ <- there are lots of options including the length of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at all possible, find an easy way to distinguish the fields you need to validate, like [Tim Bolton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992437/tim-bolton) suggested with ID attributes on the elements, or perhaps by CSS Classes like below (i.e., the "needs6" class):

```
<form>
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check needs6"> 
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check needs6">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then your jQuery selector becomes much simpler (i.e., `$("input.needs6")`).

Once you have your inputs selected, there are many ways to validate them.
Personally, I would use the following method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testFor6 = function () {
        var allHave6 = true;
        $("input.needs6").each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var value = input.val();
            if (!value.match(/\d{6}/g)) {
                allHave6 = false;
                input.addClass('doesNotHave6');
            } else {
                input.removeClass('doesNotHave6');
            }
        });

        return allHave6;
    };
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
        var allHave6 = testFor6();
        if (!allHave6) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Cancel event-bubbling.
        }
        return allHave6;        //Prevent form submission when false.
    });
});
```

If you want to see this in action, pop it into http://jsfiddle.net/ and test it, although you may want to combine this with some sample CSS classes to see it working. Samples below.

```
.needs6 {background-color: yellow;}
.doesNotHave6 {background-color: red;}
```

Hope this helps,

Pete

Addendum:

Do you mean spaces...

```
<form>
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <!-- here? --><label><!-- here? -->6 digit</label><!-- here? --><input value="1" type="text" class="check needs6" value="<!-- here? -->"> 
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check needs6">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Please clarify.

---

Certainly!

Simply change the input loop function to any portion of the following...

```
$("input.needs6").each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var value = input.val();
    //You can use this to trim.
    var trimmedValue = value.replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace(/^\s\s*/, '');
    //You can use this to find leading whitespace.
    var hasLeadingSpaces = value.match(/^\s\s*/, '');
    //You can use this to find trailing whitespace.
    var hasTrailingSpaces = value.match(/\s\s*$/, '');
    if (hasLeadingSpaces) {
        //Do something
    }
    if (hasTrailingSpaces) {
        //Do something
    }
    //Check original value
    if (!value.match(/\d{6}/g)) {
        allHave6 = false;
        input.addClass('doesNotHave6');
    } else {
        input.removeClass('doesNotHave6');
    }
    //Check trimmed value
    if (!trimmedValue.match(/\d{6}/g)) {
        allHave6 = false;
        input.addClass('doesNotHave6');
    } else {
        input.removeClass('doesNotHave6');
    }
});
```

Comment: Works Beautifully! Wonderful and thriving jquery community here! Thank you all! Any easy way to detect spaces at the beginning of the label?

Comment: Meaning if they copy and paste and there is any spaces at the beginning or end of the input field. Almost like a trim() function in c#

Answer (score 2):

Tim Bolton got it almost right, though he is checking if the value is lower than 5, he is not testing the number of digits. i would do it like this:

```
function isValidForm(){
   var labels = $('form labels');
   $(labels).each(function(){
      var inputText = $(this).next();
      if($(inputText).val().length < 6 || isNaN($(inputText).val())) {
         $(inputText).css('color', 'red'); // you can do whatever you want to show the field is not properly filled
         return false;
      }         
   })
   return true;
}
```

then, on form submission, all you have to do is:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   if(!isValidForm()){
      alert('please fix the errors');
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: You're right about the numeric evaluation (missed that one)! He does want to test if they're less than 6 though, not exactly equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to set the `for` attribute on your `label`'s.  You'll also want to set an ID for the inputs for the `label` to recognize.  That should arm you with the proper hooks to do what you want (or at least be set up appropriately).

With your current setup, try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('label').each(function() {
                var len = $(this).next().length;
                if(len < 5) { 
                    alert('Too Short!');
                } else { $('#form').submit();
            });
        })
    });
</script>
<form id="form">
    <label>Test</label><input value="asdfassd1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check"> 
    <label>6 digit</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <label>Test</label><input value="1" type="text" class="check">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The purpose of a `label` is to be associated with a form-related element via an `id`:**

```
<label for="digits">Enter Digits</label>
<input type="text" id="digits" />
```

See documentation for [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label). Given that all your `input`s should have an `id` if they have a label, try the following:

```
$('#inputID').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val().match(/^\d{6,}$/)) {
        alert('incorrect formatting!');
    }
});
```

which tests the value of the selected input against a **regular expression** for "all digits, at least six".

- [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cPx3B/)

I think [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are the most concise and portable way of validating simple inputs.